# Power BI Embedded in Dot Net Nuke without SDK

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We have certain reports published in the power bi service and want to embedd in the Dot Net Nuke(It is a CMS website). So i could not use the SDK(or the samples on github). I noticed that there is an option called Rest API using which we can embedd to a web site.

This is the URL i feel should work for my purpose

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreport#code-try-0

But I am unable to find any sample code to understand how to pass the authentication and load the report.

Can someone help provide some sample code on how to pass the authentication and how to render the embedded URL in response.

Please not the users of the CMS website does not have power bi accounts, but we have procured one Pro licence and embedded capacity.

Comment: In theory you can do it with client JavaScript only, but it will be insecure. To protect access tokens you need server side code. For authentication use [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/ADAL-basics), then use [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript). You can try it in the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html).

Comment: I am struggling to understand the how to do authentication. I have existing where i can plugin .Net code. Can i access the tokens in C# somehow. Do you have any references.